# Language translation in uipath

Tags: resolution, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

I want to change some text file which is hindi to english by using uipath studio

Text file is in notepad contains hindi words

Need to read that file and translate hindi words into english

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution that's already included UiPath Studio, there is none. All of your options will be paid.

That said, there are several paid options:

- [Microsoft Translator](https://marketplace.uipath.com/listings/microsoft-translator) custom activities
- [UiPath.Cognitive.Activities.Text.Analysis.GoogleTextTranslate](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/other/latest/user-guide/google-text-translate), which requires a Google cloud account
- [`Translate Text` activity](https://docs.uipath.com/marketplace/automation-cloud/latest/user-guide/translate-text) available in the marketplace that requires an IBM Cloud account

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite open and may not have a direct answer.

You can, and need to, build the translator yourself using the free/community version of UiPath Studio (X).

Go to youtube and you will find plenty of tutorials on how to build it.

There may not be direct example, but put together the processes of using "Type Into" from your notepad to the browser, then find other processes of using "Get Text" of the translated text from the browser to another notepad, ie, screen scrapping.